# How to declare the text size for all Text fields within a row / column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

How can I specify a textSize for all text elements within a Column / Row?

I have difficulty finding a method, which helps me doing something like the `UnspecifiedFontSize` (pseudo code):

```
Row {
    UnspecifiedFontSize(size= 128.dp) {
            Text("ping")
            Text("pong")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see [androidx/compose/material/Text.kt#110](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Text.kt#110)
you can use `LocalTextStyle`

```
@Composable
fun Text114514() {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalTextStyle provides TextStyle(fontSize = 80.sp)
    ) {
        Row {
            Text("ping")
            Text("pong")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can merge the default `TextStyle` with your custom `fontSize` using:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalTextStyle provides LocalTextStyle.current.copy(fontSize = 128.dp)
) {
    Row {
        Text("ping")
        Text("pong")
    }
}
```